# Read UTF-16 file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, filereader, utf-16

I have a UTF-16 encoded file

```
$ file myFile.csv
myFile.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

But when I open it with JavaScript using the following code

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open( "GET", url, false );
http.send( null );  
var csv = http.responseText;
```

The resulting `csv` variable is interpreted as the file was in UTF-8.

The result is this:

```
[10:58:19.294] "��D\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00_\x001\x00,\x00S\x00y\x00s\x00t\x00e\x00m\x00_\x00S\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00,\x00S\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00_\x00C\x00h\x00a\x00n\x00g\x00e\x00_\x00C\x00o\x00u\x00n\x00t\x00_\x002\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x00/\x002\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00,\x00C\x00l\x00o\x00s\x00e\x00d\x00,\x001\x005\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x00/\x002\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00,\x00N\x00e\x00w\x00,\x001\x008\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x00/\x002\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00,\x00R\x00e\x00s\x00o\x00l\x00v\x00e\x00d\x00,\x003\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x00/\x003\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00,\x00D\x00e\x00f\x00e\x00r\x00r\x00e\x00d\x00,\x001\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x00/\x003\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00,\x00N\x00e\x00w\x00,\x006\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x00/\x003\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00,\x00R\x00e\x00s\x00o\x00l\x00v\x00e\x00d\x00,\x001\x00\r\x00\n\x001\x00/\x003\x00/\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00,\x00V\x00e\x00r\x00i\x00f\x00i\x00e\x00d\x00,\x009\x00\r\x00\n" […]
```

Every other character is the NUL character (represented as \x00), so it messes up all my further character counting and parsing. The first two charactes are "replacement" characters, because in the real file, the first 16 bits represent the "little-endian UTF-16 BOM", which results in illigal characters in UTF-8.

When I view the file in HEX format, I have the following first lines:

```
0000000: fffe 4400 6100 7400 6500 5f00 3100 2c00  ..D.a.t.e._.1.,.
0000010: 5300 7900 7300 7400 6500 6d00 5f00 5300  S.y.s.t.e.m._.S.
0000020: 7400 6100 7400 6500 2c00 5300 7400 6100  t.a.t.e.,.S.t.a.
0000030: 7400 6500 5f00 4300 6800 6100 6e00 6700  t.e._.C.h.a.n.g.
0000040: 6500 5f00 4300 6f00 7500 6e00 7400 5f00  e._.C.o.u.n.t._.
0000050: 3200 0d00 0a00 3100 2f00 3200 2f00 3200  2.....1./.2./.2.
0000060: 3000 3100 3200 2c00 4300 6c00 6f00 7300  0.1.2.,.C.l.o.s.
0000070: 6500 6400 2c00 3100 3500 0d00 0a00 3100  e.d.,.1.5.....1.
0000080: 2f00 3200 2f00 3200 3000 3100 3200 2c00  /.2./.2.0.1.2.,.
0000090: 4e00 6500 7700 2c00 3100 3800 0d00 0a00  N.e.w.,.1.8.....
```

I wonder why it doesn't interprete the file as UTF-16 (as it starts with a correct BOM), and if there's any way to change it. It should be able to automatically determine the format in some way (so also work with UTF-8, and other common ones like ASCII and ANSI).

For testing the library, I read the file with XMLHttpRequest, but in the deployed library, it should read files via the JAvascript FileReader API. Does this make any difference?

I tested it on Linux (Firefox and Chrome) and on Windows (Firefox), so it seems browser and OS independent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [setRequestHeader method](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader)? I think you should be able to specify the content type. Additionally I suspect the browser will pick up on that particular detail.

What led me to this was(at least in part) the first example on [this page](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I now tried the following code:http://pastebin.com/47jLTwZD

but no change. The resulting csv string is still the same (with the NUL and replacement chars)

Comment: Even if I change the character encoding to UTF-16le hard coded, all UTF-8 files still parse perfectly, but the UTF-16 file gives an unparsable CSV.